# Regex works on chrome and other browsers but returns invalid error on safari

Tags: regex

The below regex works on chrome but is having an issue in safari as it contains a lookbehind ,Here in need that lookahead for the proper working so is there any other way by which it could be resolved?

```
(#[a-zA-Z0-9_(,)]{1,30})+(?<!,)$
```

The regex im trying to accomplish is :

- That it it should start with #
- Then the string should be seperated by 'comma'
- Then the string could not end with 'comma'
- After 'comma' if a new string is entered then hash should start
- The maxlimit of each string is 30 and min is 1

It should accept:

```
#tag 
#tag_1,#tag2 
#tag1,#tag2,#tag3
```

It should not accept:-

```
# 
#tag(with more than 30 characters) 
# tag1, 
#tag:///
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish with this regex?

Comment: I think you mean lookbehind right?

Comment: ys its look behind  @Thefourthbird

Comment: The regex im trying to accomplish is That it it should start with # ,Then the string should be seperated by 'comma' , Then the string could not end with 'comma', After 'comma' if a new string is entered then hash should start ,The maxlimit of each string is 30 and min is 1 @depperm

Comment: It should accept:-
1.    #tag
2.   #tag_1,#tag2
3.   #tag1,#tag2,#tag3  
It should not accept:-
1.      #
2.     #tag(with more than 30 characters)
3.    # tag1,
4.   #tag:///   @MikeM

Comment: its the . of 1. @MikeM

Comment: Ys sry for not providing iit properly @MikeM

Answer (score 1):

You can take out the comma of the character class, and prepend it on every iteration

The capture group can be a non capturing one if you need a match only.

```
^#[a-zA-Z0-9_()]{1,30}(?:,#[a-zA-Z0-9_()]{1,30})*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `#[a-zA-Z0-9_()]{1,30}` Match 1-30 repetitions of the character class without the comma
- `(?:,#[a-zA-Z0-9_()]{1,30})*` Optionally repeat `,` and  1-30 repetitions of the character class without the comma
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uOi2yw/1)

Comment: But this does match the following string condition
#taggg
it accepts :-
#tagg,#tag1, ....... @The fourth bird

Comment: @am's That is what I understood from the question, is that not ok? What are the expected matches?

Comment: It should accept:- 1.#tag 2.#tag_1,#tag2 3.#tag1,#tag2,#tag3 It should not accept:- 1.# 2.#tag(with more than 30 characters) 3.# tag1, 4.#tag:///   These are the expected matches and non matches @The fourth bird

Comment: @am's It matches all those requirements, see https://regex101.com/r/ymGv9c/1

Comment: Yes This matches my requirement Thanks for the help @The fourth bird